# Unity says API level is too low

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-tools, google-cardboard, android-sdk-2.3

The exact error:

```
Minimum API Level Not Supported on Requested VR Device
Cardboard Requires a Minimum API Level of 19
```

Though in the Android SDK Manager, it says I have revisions 25.2.5, 25.0.5, 
 and 25.0.3 installed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to change this Minimun API Level from the Editor.

Go to Edit --> Project Settings --> Player --> Other Settings --> Identification --> Minimium API Level --> Android 4.4 'Kit Kat' (API Level 19) or anything above.

Also change *Target API Level* to *Automatic (highest installed)*.

If this did not work, make sure to download API Level 19 (Android 4.4.2) or any level above from the Android SDK Manager. After that repeat what's in this answer.

Comment: When you are new a software, you don't have to know every settings in it.

Comment: Thank you!!! After hours, I finally solved with this solution